# Expo: How to create a file in app's internal/private folder

Tags: expo, expo-file-system

I have explored expo FileSystem APIs but it doesn't give any option to store files on app's internal folders.
All the files saved using createFileAsync API with Document dir are showing up on user's device file manager app.
Is there any way to do it without ejecting expo?